# Logical error keeps for loop looping infinite, Why?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a JavaScript devowelizer, but I'm producing an infinite loop.
I'm hoping someone on Stack Overflow can help?

The code =>

```
let userWord = prompt("Type a word to devowelize: ");
userWord = Devowelize(userWord);
alert(userWord);

function Devowelize(word) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
    let eatChars = "aeiou"

    for (let i2 = 0; i2 <= eatChars.length;) {
      if (word[i] == eatChars[i2] &&
        word[i] != "") {
        word = word.replace(word[i], "");
      } else {
        i2++;
      }
    }
  }

  return word
}
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. You should also learn about `map()` and `filter()` functions for arrays.

Comment: You never increment `i2`.

Comment: "devowelizer" is a fantastic word.

Comment: @Heretic Yes, they are, theoretically.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That isn't true...`i2` increments in the `else` clause.

Comment: you're modifying `word` inside the loop by removing chars `word = word.replace(word[i], "");`. this affects the outer loop since it depends on `word` length.

Comment: Yeah, I was editing the comment. If the `if` condition matches, it will never increment `i2` and gets stuck.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Wouldn't that fix itself on the next iteration? The condition would now be false, thus hitting `i2++` and moving on to the next vowel.

Comment: It’s probably because you iterate until `<=`, and eventually both values are `undefined` and get stuck in the inner loop.

Comment: Replace `<= word.length` with `< word.length` and likewise in the second loop and it works fine.

Comment: Well, it doesn't quite work, it has a bug with consecutive descending vowels ("ui" for instance), but it doesn't infinite loop at least.

Comment: I'm simply amazed by this community!... I would never have expected to receive answers in minutes, so thank you very much to you all!

Comment: @JohnMontgomery the foor loops now work with your correction, and it turns out I forgot that string.length returns the actual amount of charachters, starting with 1, and not like arrays index which start at 0. I know need to correct the rest of the logical errors.

Comment: Can annyone tell why I received 2 downvotes?... Was it because of typing mistakes?... Or was my help plee not a question?... It would help to make my future questions better.

Comment: try return word.replace('[aeiou]','');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using here `for (let i = 0; i <= word.length; i++)` this part `i <= word.length`  isn't correct because you will try to access the array `word` using the `i` index after that in your code so in the last iteration you will access an index which is not defined by your array the last index of an array in javascript is always **arrayLength-1** if you access an item which is out of the array you will get an undefined as value which will generates an infinte loop in your case you have done the same thing here `for (let i2 = 0; i2 <= eatChars.length;)` but the first loop is the responsible of the infinite loop in your code

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for explaining it thoroughly. I'm still new to programming, and I appreciate your time and effort to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost there, but you're trying to solve this problem in a very roundabout way. Let's make it a bit easier to understand.

In JavaScript, you can easily check if a string contains another string. For example, if we wanted to check if a character was in a string, we could do this:

```js
let eatChars = "aeiou"

eatChars.includes('e') === true
```

So knowing that we can do that in a single statement, let's reuse some of the code you've got and substitute the character 'e' for the characters in your word.

```js
let outWord = ""
const eatChars = "aeiou"
// '<= word.length' becomes this, because the string positions only go up to 'word.length - 1
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (!eatChars.includes(word[i])) { // so the character isn't a vowel
       outWord += word[i]
    }
}
return outWord
```

The comments mention learning about 'map' and 'filter'. I'd recommend using a reducer for this if you wanted to be fancy! You could try something like this:

```js
const devowel = (word) => Array.from(word).reduce((out, currentCharacter) => ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposed answer, I still have a lot to learn.